# Robocopy Files and Folder Missing

Tags: robocopy

I am using the following robocopy command.

ROBOCOPY "C:\Users\Office\Pictures\Drew\Family Pictures" B:\Backup /S /E

I can never find the files after they are copied.  Robocopy see the files because when I rerun the command it doesn't copy any files since they already exist.  attrib can't find the destination folder.  File explorer and Disk management don't see any disk usage.  I have tried /A-:SH with no help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccThB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my pc,

Why do you use 2 opposite parameters ?

/S = copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones

/E = copy Subdirectories, including Empty ones

Try the following

```
robocopy "C:\Users\Office\Pictures\Drew\Family Pictures" "B:\Backup/Family Pictures" /e
```